# RoleExist MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to get if the Role exist

This is the code

```
if (!Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
                    {
                        context.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole()
                        {
                            Name = "Admin"
                        });
                    }
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(user.Id, "Admin");

}
```

But it throws a error about db connection that could not be established on the if(!Roles.RoleExists("Admin") part. This is a addition on the Register Method in the Account Controller, What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That doesnt work with MVC5 and ASP.net Identity anymore. You need to get a hold of RoleManager class instance.

See this link for more info:
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc